# Fiberglass vs Rockwool: What are their pros / cons in making acoustic panels?

Tags: recording, sound, acoustics, studio

I'm trying to decide which material to use for DIY acoustic panels. [Rockwool](http://www.lowes.com/pd/ROCKWOOL-SAFE-n-SOUND-R-Stone-Wool-Batt-Insulation-with-Sound-Barrier-15-25-in-W-x-47-in-L/3394032) and [Fiberglass](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Owens-Corning-R-13-EcoTouch-PINK-Unfaced-Fiberglass-Insulation-Batt-23-in-x-93-in-U73/202837087) have [comparable](https://www.soundproofingtips.com/soundproofing-insulation/) sound absorption except for ~125 Hz where Rockwool performs much better. But I can buy 3x as much fiberglass than rockwool for the same price, covering nearly my entire room. Should I go for less of the better material or more of the cheaper option?

Most studios I've seen aren't entirely covered in acoustic panels.

The fiberglass is also 0.5" thicker.

Comment: What's your end goal - sound shaping within the room or transmission prevention? If it's shaping, then buy whichever best suits your existing acoustic profile measurements. If transmission, forget it.

Comment: I want to reduce reflections; I don't care about sound escaping.

Comment: if you want to put it, open-faced on an internal wall, you don't want either - they flake, shed dust & are itchy. Look at acoustic panels & traps instead, something designed to also be seen, rather than put inside the walls.

Comment: Even if they're covered up on both sides?

Comment: I wouldn't want to be in the same room as fibreglass, whatever it's covered in. Rockwool you could probably get away with.

Comment: Since low frequency standing waves are one of the hardest things to mitigate in a room, I’d say the rock wool has a distinct advantage in terms of greater control over the lows. If you might build dedicated bass traps in the future, then the rock wool has less of an advantage. To me this question has some opinion and also more information needed elements. Neither is “better”, a lot depends on the initial conditions, overall design parameters, and desired result.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I imagine as long as it's sufficiently covered and sealed, the fibreglass shouldn't pose too much of an issue. Here's some related articles on the subject from the UK's *Sound On Sound* magazine (no affiliation).

[Room Improvement (covers rockwool etc.)](https://www.soundonsound.com/techniques/room-improvement)

[Are mineral-wool acoustic panels safe?](https://www.soundonsound.com/sound-advice/q-are-mineral-wool-acoustic-panels-safe)

[Choosing & Using Porous Absorbers](https://www.soundonsound.com/reviews/choosing-using-porous-absorbers)

[Practical Acoustic Treatment](https://www.soundonsound.com/techniques/practical-acoustic-treatment-part-2)

There's also [this post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/106136/wrapping-fibreglass-rock-wool-to-seal-in-fibres-in-acoustic-panels-bass-traps) on DIY.